# Questions about GridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: winforms, telerik

I'm using Telerik UI Winforms and I have some questions about GridViewComboBoxColumn:

1. How can I loop through GridViewComboBoxColumn's items
2. How to select an item based on a field in datatable for example:

if I have a column "Products" has the below items

```
ProductA
ProductB
ProductC
```

I want to set each row of the GridViewComboBoxColumn to the same product of the datatable
3- How to change the text of a cell in GridViewComboBoxColumn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. GridViewComboBoxColumn has a DataSource, which should be assigned to your Products collection. You can iterate the items in the DataSource if need be.
2. The selected item is based on the field in the GRID DataSource. E.g if the grid has a column ProductID and it has value 2, and your MCCB column a data source such as ProductID ProductName, and ValueMember is ProductID, the grid's value 2 will be matched to the item with value 2 in the mccb column data source.

Here you can find more info about this column: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/columns/column-types/gridviewmulticomboboxcolumn

Comment: Thanks checho, I connect the GridViewComboBoxColumn to the Datatable and its been filled from it by DisplayMember and ValueMember... no problem with that
What I need is when I search the database I get the results in Datatable so I want to connect it to the grid view and display each row is what is it in the datatable and keep the GridViewComboBoxColumn filled with all items to be able to change it later if needed
So I need to know how to connect it to the datatable and display the text as it in DataTable

Comment: I am sorry, I am not clear with your scenario. I you can provide some code and better explanation, I will be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you checho for your reply I solved this issue
after I passed the FiledName to the control eveything worked properly